# Obtener una serie de datos mediante pandas

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, csv

Hola que tal? Buenas tardes, quería saber si alguien podría ayudarme con una duda que tengo.
Muestro a continuación el código:

```
if num == 4:
            df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv', index_col='numero')
            experiencia = df['experiencia']
            media = statistics.mean(experiencia)
            mediana = statistics.median(experiencia)
            moda = statistics.mode(experiencia)
            varianza = statistics.stdev(experiencia)
            desviacion_estandar = statistics.pstdev(experiencia)
            print('La experiencia promedio es de:', round(media,2))
            print('La mediana de las experiencias laborales es de:', round(mediana,2))
            print('La experiencia con mayor frecuencia es:', round(moda,2))
            print('La varianza de la experiencia es de:', round(varianza,2))
            print('La desviacion estandar de las experiencias laborales es:', round(desviacion_estandar,2))
            desviacion_positiva = media + desviacion_estandar
            desviacion_negativa = media - desviacion_estandar
            print('Las experiencias laborales normales son aquellas que se encuentran dentro de:', round(desviacion_negativa, 2), 'y', round(desviacion_positiva, 2))
```

La pregunta es: Como hago para obtener datos del archivo csv mediante la libreria pandas que sean correspondientes a una condicion. En este caso la condicion es que tengo que obtener los datos de la columna `'experiencia'` (la cual esta en el archivo csv) y mostrar cuales son 'normales'. La valores normales serian aquellos que sean mayores a la `'desviacion_negativa'` y a su vez sean menores que la `'desviacion_positiva'`.
Desde ya muchas gracias y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Si lo necesitan puedo adjuntar mas codigo

Comment: `experiencia[experiencia.between(desviacion_negativa, desviacion_positiva)]`

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo y te aviso cualquier duda